# Android, Use Timer to do a task at different times?

Tags: android, timer

I searched other posts and I didn't find a case matching my problem, so please do not refer me to other posts.

I have a list of hundreds of different times starting like the below list:

timeList = {5, 13, 21, 40, ...}.

Suppose that they are saved in an arraylist. That means some task must be executed at 5 secs, 13 secs,... from a starting point . How can I use a Timer or any other way to achieve this? 
Also I may have the timeList in a format like this if it helps:

timeList = {8:05, 8:13, 8:21, 8:40, ...}.

My current timer is like this:

```
    timer = new Timer();
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {

        synchronized public void run() {
            //do some task
        }
    }, startPoint, Period);
```

But this is obviously working at fixed rate!

Comment: Start a timer with start point 5 (timeList[0]), inside the run method, do your task and start a new timer with start point 13 (timeList[1]) and so on.

Comment: What should happen when the app is closed? Timers are not persistent

Comment: Nice work around. But I think there must be a way i give the list to a timer or sth like that and it starts executing some task at the specified time points.@bigdestroyer

Comment: I run the timer in a service. Isn't it enough? or is there a persistent way to do so? @TimCastelijns

Comment: Don't use timers when they should be executed in background. Use `CountDownTimer` instead.

Comment: *I run the timer in a service. Isn't it enough?* It depends on your requirements. A service cannot be guaranteed to run at all times, so there will be times when your timers are not going to be triggered because the service is not running.

Comment: You can do it with AlarmManager (the system triggers these alarms) but there is a limit on how many alarms you can set at a time. You'd have to keep track of a pool of alarms and schedule a new one when a slot is freed

Comment: Now another question raises! You say there is no guarantee a service runs at all times. Let go of scheduled tasks, How can i have a background process which runs continuously until the user explicitly stop it? I know it's another question and I may ask it as a new post. But first I want to make sure is there a way?@TimCastelijns

Answer (score 0):

By using  [Timer.schedule(TimerTask task, long delay)](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html#schedule(java.util.TimerTask,%20long)), set all your timers and wait for them to execute

Assuming you are getting in MM:SS format (ex: 8:58):

```
    ArrayList<String> your_arraylist = new ArrayList<String>();
    //your list above, fill it with MM:SS

    final ArrayList<Long> seconds    = new ArrayList<Long>();
    final ArrayList<Long> minutes    = new ArrayList<Long>();
    long first_minute;

    for (String time : your_arraylist) {
        minutes.add(Long.parseLong(time.split(":")[0]));
        seconds.add(Long.parseLong(time.split(":")[1]));
    }

    first_minute = minutes.get(0);        

    for (int i = 0; i < seconds.size(); i++) {
        long waiting_duration;

        if (seconds.get(i) < Calendar.SECOND) {
            waiting_duration = (60 - Calendar.SECOND + seconds.get(i)) * 1000;
        }
        else {
            waiting_duration = (seconds.get(i) - Calendar.SECOND) * 1000;
        }

        waiting_duration += (minutes.get(i) - first_minute) * 60 * 1000;

        Timer timer          = new Timer();
        TimerTask timer_task = new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // do jobs
            }
        };
        timer.schedule(timer_task, waiting_duration);
    }
```

Comment: This is for executing the same task on different seconds of yours. If you are gonna do different jobs on different seconds let me know

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Does each cycle of the for loop is executed after timer.schedule(timer_task, waiting_duration) is executed? If not, Then It's not applicable, because of large number of time points!

Comment: Yes, but doesn't wait for the timer. It just sets the timer and continues to set next one

Comment: Each cycle is responsible for setting the timer only, tasks will run after a certain duration from different thread.

Comment: So is it efficient and applicable for a large list of 1000 time points?@BurakDay

Comment: For the same minute? yes. For different minutes, it still needs implementation. For instance; let's assume you have 5 timestamps on the same minute: 8:08, 8:13, 8:23, 8:31, 8:47. On the first second of 9th minute, there must be a calculation like

Comment: `int first_minute = 8;


waiting duration += (Calendar.MINUTE - first_minute) * 60 * 1000` then the loop is gonna be fine.

Comment: @morgan Edited the post

Answer (score 0):

Don't use Timer use a Handler instead.

```
private int[] mTimeList = {5000, 2000, 7000, 4000};
private int mCount;
private int mDelay;
private Handler mHandler = new Handler();



 private void initRepeatedTimer() {
    mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            Log.e(TAG, "run: " + mCount);
            mDelay = mTimeList[mCount];
            if (mCount < mTimeList.length - 1)
                mCount++;
            else
                mCount = 0;
            mHandler.postDelayed(this, mDelay);
        }
    }, mDelay);
}
```

You wil notice that the log is printed as per delay in the list.

Comment: if its a very long process use a separate variable wth value mTimeList.length

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But why not use Timer? It's gonna be a service which is running all day long and all weekdays. Isn't a timer persistent enough? If so, is a handler more convinient? @yuen-shi

Comment: There is high chance of memory leaks in Timer compared to Handler.

Check for lint warning for memory leaks.
Check memory monitor and make sure the graph is stable.
According to my knowledge Timer can't be rescheduled.

Handler is comparatively good. New TimerTask has to be created everytime if you use a Timer, handler you can resuse.

Another solution is to use RxAndroid.
If you are confident with RxAndroid better try it. I am a beginner in Rx so can't give a solution in it.